# How can I make rpm -q --whatprovides see the same libraries as yum provides?

Tags: yum, rpm

For context, I'm trying to set up a Chef script that calls out to a third-party installer. In the third-party installer is this function:

```
isLibbz()
{
   rpm -q --whatprovides libbz2.so.1 >/dev/null 2>&1
   [ "$?" = "0" ] && return 1 || return 0
}
```

Thanks to the internet, I know that bzip2-libs has the libbz2.so.1 package, so I installed it (Chef uses yum to do this under the covers). The installer still fails, though, because of the above.

```
$ rpm -q --whatprovides libbz2.so.1
no package provides libbz2.so.1
```

Yum doesn't seem to have this issue.

```
$ yum provides libbz2.so.1
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * CentOS-Base: mirror.den1.denvercolo.net
bzip2-libs-1.0.6-13.el7.i686 : Libraries for applications using bzip2
Repo        : CentOS-Base
Matched from:
Provides    : libbz2.so.1
```

rpm also seems to find the installed library well enough.

```
$ rpm -q -l bzip2-libs
/usr/lib64/libbz2.so.1
/usr/lib64/libbz2.so.1.0.6
/usr/share/doc/bzip2-libs-1.0.6
/usr/share/doc/bzip2-libs-1.0.6/LICENSE
```

I would strongly prefer a fix that doesn't involve changing a giant installer that might change with new software versions. Is there anything I can do to make rpm -q --whatprovides do what our vendor wants it to do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give it the full path to the file.

```
[root@centos75 ~]# rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/lib64/libbz2.so.1
bzip2-libs-1.0.6-13.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: If that was a hard requirement, wouldn't the installer fail for everyone under all circumstances except in the oddball case that someone ran the installer from inside /usr/lib64?

Comment: That's a question for whomever wrote the installer.  Not specifying the full path will fail even if you ran the rpm command from inside /usr/lib64 without the full path.

Comment: Virtual libraries do NOT have full paths -- that's the point. So what command can resolve dependencies seen with `rpm -qR`?